# dense_rank over boolean column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions, dense-rank

Good day. I have a permutated table with condition and I am running redshift DB. This is a table with events log and I splitted it into session start (bool = 1) and session continue (bool = 0) like this:

```
=======================
| ID    |  BOOL      |
=======================
|  1    |      0     |
|  2    |      1     | 
|  3    |      0     |
|  4    |      0     |
|  5    |      0     |
|  6    |      0     |
|  7    |      0     |
|  8    |      0     |
|  9    |      0     |
|  10   |      0     |
|  11   |      1     | 
|  12   |      0     |
|  13   |      0     |
|  14   |      1     |
|  15   |      0     |
|  16   |      0     |
=======================
```

I need to create sesssion_id column with something like dense_rank:

```
================================
| ID    |  BOOL      |  D_RANK |
================================
|  1    |      0     |    1    |
|  2    |      1     |    2    | 
|  3    |      0     |    2    |
|  4    |      0     |    2    |
|  5    |      0     |    2    |
|  6    |      0     |    2    |
|  7    |      0     |    2    |
|  8    |      0     |    2    |
|  9    |      0     |    2    |
|  10   |      0     |    2    |
|  11   |      1     |    3    |
|  12   |      0     |    3    |
|  13   |      0     |    3    |
|  14   |      1     |    4    |
|  15   |      0     |    4    |
|  16   |      0     |    4    |
================================
```

Is there any option to do this? Would appreciate any help.

Comment: I think the value of the second row should be `2` not `1`.

Comment: Yes, you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a cumulative sum.  Assuming that `bool` is the start of a new session:

```
select t.*,
       sum(bool) over (order by id) as session_id
from t;
```

Note:  This will start at `0`.  You can add `1` if you need.